# Alternativa: separar JS de HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, json

Mi proyecto consta de un html y un archivo js que simulan el funcionamiento de un reloj analogico. Funciona correctamente pero quisiera no tener que hacer mención a la funcion js desde el html () como lo tengo y buscar una alternativa haciendo referencia desde un script por ejemplo solamente y añadir una llamada o un método en el archivo js que lanze la funcion

html:

```
<body onload="funcionReloj()">

   <div id="cajacontenido">
        <div id="aplicacion">
            <div id="CajaReloj">
                <img id="segundos" src="./IMG/Aguja3.png" alt="Manilla segundos reloj" />
                <img id="minutos" src="./IMG/Aguja2.png" alt="Manilla pequeña reloj" />
                <img id="hora" src="./IMG/Aguja1.png" alt="Manilla grande reloj" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y en cuanto a mi archivo js:

```
function funcionReloj() {
    var momentoActual = new Date();//Crea hora
    var horaActual = momentoActual.getHours();//Extraemos Hora
    var minutoActual = momentoActual.getMinutes();//Extraemos Minutos
    var segundoActual = momentoActual.getSeconds();//Extraemos Segundos

    //Identificadores para elementos
    var hora = document.getElementById('hora');
    var minutos = document.getElementById('minutos');
    var segundos = document.getElementById('segundos');

    function cambiarHora() {
        //Calcular grados por hora (30deg cada hora, 30*12=360º)
         var horaActualGrados = horaActual * 30 + "deg";
         hora.style.transform = "rotate(" + horaActualGrados + ")";

        //Calcular grados cada minuto (6deg cada minuto, 6*6=360º)
         var minutoActualGrados = minutoActual * 6 + "deg";
         minutos.style.transform = "rotate(" + minutoActualGrados + ")";
    }

    function cambiarSegundos() {
        //Calcular grados cada segundo (6deg cada segundo, 6*6=360º)
        var segundoActualGrados = segundoActual * 6 + "deg";
        segundos.style.transform = "rotate(" + segundoActualGrados + ")";
    }

    cambiarHora();
    cambiarSegundos();

    //Actualizar reloj
    setTimeout("funcionReloj()",1000);

    //Actualizar reloj cada segundo
    //    setTimeout("cambiarSegundos()",1000);
}
```

Gracias

Comment: pero si en tu archivo .php solo tienes código javascript por que no pasarlo a un archivo con extensión .js?

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta que metí la pata..lo q tngo es un archivo js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En lugar de poner el `onLoad` en la etiqueta, puedes ponerlo en tu fichero .js como un evento de la ventana. Cuando se cargue la ventana, lanza tu función. Algo como esto:

```js
function tuFuncion() {
  // ....
  console.log("Se ejecutó al cargar");
}

window.addEventListener("load", tuFuncion);
```

Con [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) asocias el tipo de evento que quieres que lance la ejecución de la función (aquí puedes ver una [lista de los tipos de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events)). En el código de arriba estás diciendo que cuando la ventana (`window`) se carge (`load`) se llame a una función (`tuFuncion`).

En tu caso sería así:

```
window.addEventListener("load", funcionReloj);
```

Comment: Gracias!, me ha servido tu respuesta!!

Answer (score 4):

Similar a lo que ya te comentaron, quita el llamado a la función de la etiqueta `body` y asignalo al eventpo `DOMContentLoaded` pues este mismo se ejecuta cuando la página HTML esta totalmente cargada

Con lo que quedaría así tu ejercicio

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejempl</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
    
       <div id="cajacontenido">
            <div id="aplicacion">
                <div id="CajaReloj">
                    <img id="segundos" src="./IMG/Aguja3.png" alt="Manilla segundos reloj" />
                    <img id="minutos" src="./IMG/Aguja2.png" alt="Manilla pequeña reloj" />
                    <img id="hora" src="./IMG/Aguja1.png" alt="Manilla grande reloj" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
      function funcionReloj() {
        var momentoActual = new Date();//Crea hora
        var horaActual = momentoActual.getHours();//Extraemos Hora
        var minutoActual = momentoActual.getMinutes();//Extraemos Minutos
        var segundoActual = momentoActual.getSeconds();//Extraemos Segundos
    
        //Identificadores para elementos
        var hora = document.getElementById('hora');
        var minutos = document.getElementById('minutos');
        var segundos = document.getElementById('segundos');
    
        function cambiarHora() {
            //Calcular grados por hora (30deg cada hora, 30*12=360º)
             var horaActualGrados = horaActual * 30 + "deg";
             hora.style.transform = "rotate(" + horaActualGrados + ")";
    
            //Calcular grados cada minuto (6deg cada minuto, 6*6=360º)
             var minutoActualGrados = minutoActual * 6 + "deg";
             minutos.style.transform = "rotate(" + minutoActualGrados + ")";
        }
    
        function cambiarSegundos() {
            //Calcular grados cada segundo (6deg cada segundo, 6*6=360º)
            var segundoActualGrados = segundoActual * 6 + "deg";
            segundos.style.transform = "rotate(" + segundoActualGrados + ")";
        }
    
        cambiarHora();
        cambiarSegundos();
    
        //Actualizar reloj
        setTimeout("funcionReloj()",1000);
    
        //Actualizar reloj cada segundo
        //    setTimeout("cambiarSegundos()",1000);
    }
      
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funcionReloj())
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Explicación

- Es decir primero va todo el código que logra la funcionalidad del reloj
- Posterior agregamos un `listener` al `document` para verificar cuando todo el documento este *listo*
- Como segundo argumento pasamos el nombre de la función principal que es `funcionReloj()`